# Как двумя запросами в базу данных создать новые записи в таблице и после этого создать новые ассоциированные записи в другой таблице?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql9.5

Как можно двумя запросами в базу данных выполнить следующие действия?

1. Создать несколько (много) записей в таблице **А**. (Первый SQL запрос в базу данных)
2. Получить **id** записей после их создания.
3. Создать такоже же количество записей в таблице **B**, но при этом установив связь с новосозданными записями **А**, записывая в **foreign key** поле их **id**.

Есть ли в postgresql какие-то инструменты, с помощью которых можно это реализовать? Спасибо заранее! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какую задачу решаете? В вопросе стоит тег RoR, вроде как должно рельсовых штатных средств хватать

Comment: @Василиса Я использую Rails 5 версии, и честно говоря, без сторонних библиотек создание многих записей за раз (чтобы сгенерировался запрос INSERT INTO) возможно только через чистый SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и одним всё вставить

```
create table A (id serial primary key, a text);
create table B (fk int references A(id), b text);

with inputData as (
  select 'A' a, 'X' b
  union select 'B', 'Y' 
)
, insertedA as (
    insert into A(a) 
    select a from inputData 
    returning id, a
) 
insert into B(fk, b)
select id, b 
from insertedA, inputData 
where insertedA.a = inputData.a;

select * from A;
select * from B;
```

---

> Получить id записей после их создания.

А если отвечать строго на вопрос, то используй `returning id, a`, вычитывай их после вставки в А и передавай в скрипт вставки в B.

Comment: Премного благодарен, похоже это то, что мне нужно.